# View Permissions of Netbackup 6 Windows Backup

Tags: netbackup

Can I *view* what the permissions are of a windows folder (users and groups) of a netbackup backup (without actually restoring any anywhere)?  The Java GUI would be preferable if possible.

Answer (score 1):

My resident Netbackup expert says negative.  He's tried in the past as well to no avail.